# Which way is better Extending classes or keeping them separate and creating multiple objects?

Tags: php

Can anyone let me know, when using PHP classes, what is the best way given this kind of scenario : I have 2 classes A and B, both have different functions but both will be used on the same page.

If I keep both separate I have to create 2 objects and use them and if I extend then I have to create one object. So which is the best way? Or is there any other good way for this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only `extend` a `PHP` `class` if you want to inherit variables or functions from the parent. E.g., a `Square`, `Circle`, and `Triangle` classes might extend `Shape`.

From the sounds of your post they are two separate entities, so probably worth having as two separate classes. The memory consumption from having another class will be minimal.

Answer (score 1):

If they are not related they should be seperate.
Be careful when you want to extend a class, you should put a lot of thought into it, if it really is the best way to program it.

Logic -> comfort.